# Repeat and timing load with while or for

Tags: jquery

I won't show this. You will understand by code.

I'm sorry that I do not speak English well.

I want timing if isset load file one ..start load file next from array

```
var myarray = "one.html","tow.html","three.html";

var vvvv = 1
   function slideit(){


$("#mydiv").load(myarray[vvvv], + '#title').delay(3000, function(){
$("mydivtow").load(myarray[vvvv], +'#desc').delay(3000) });

vvvv++
```

Comment: It kind of looks like your asking about a load chain however without more context I don't feel you'll get a good answer. Can you please try clarifying your question to give us more context to help you. Please see [the asking guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: function runAni(arr) {
        var $div = $('#text_wrapper');
    
        $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $div.html(value).fadeIn(3000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
            }, 1000 * index);
        });
    }
    
    var arr = ["aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbb","ccccccc", "ddddddd"];
    runAni(arr);
I want setTimeout Not specified
I want the timing until the end of the first show
Then the next begins
Because the timing offers are not the same
a 5 seconds
b 10 seconds

Comment: Ziad, I'm still not understanding the issue you're facing giving this description. Perhaps you could add to a stackblitz like (https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-so-56159566) with what's not working so we can help you. Or maybe a diagram to explain what you mean by the timing of the first show.